# Why does the photon travel differently in Earth's Atmosphere?

Tags: particle-physics, photons, atmospheric-science, wavelength, dissipation

Take a box T.V. and place it out side and notice the farther away you walk from it the red color fades only leaving the blue color. Why is that?
Deep sea plants are commonly found to be red in color while arid plants are normally green. The plants absorb all the light except the color it is. Is that suggesting that different spectrum photons behave differently? Could it also be said that in the not so vacuum of space could effect light in a adverse way not as tired light but the blue light has dissipated? Could higher energy blue photons be more likely to be absorbed than red photons in space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several effects going on.  Each of your examples has a different explanation.  Also, I'd point out a counter example: sunsets.  The red photons actually go longer without being scattered in the atmosphere, which is why the sky is blue but sunsets are red.

The TV is the hardest example for me to work with.  I haven't actually seen this effect, so I can't necessarily argue for it.  My experience is that the color of the screen at a distance is typically dominated by the color of the scene on the TV.  A nature documentary will look different from an indoor scene with warm lights.  A Star Wars screening with all the hot-pink blaster fire would look pink.  Most likely, any effect you are seeing in this TV is an effect of your eyes, but I really don't know because my experience is contrary to yours.

Plants underwater, however, have a known explanation.  Water *does* absorb the red end of the spectrum and let the blue end pass through.  That's why, if you have nice white sand on the sea floor, everything looks blue.  This means that, as you go deeper, reds start to look more and more black.  It turns out that they're actually quite nice for camouflage!  This is actually an issue for divers doing photography.  Many scenes look dull when you're down there.  Take a photo, and its just drab.  However, if you bring a camera with a strobe, which emits bright white light, you can capture all of the reds which were not visible because the red portion of the  sunlight had been absorbed on its way down!

As for the vacuum of space, there's no evidence to suggest blue gets absorbed substantially more than red.  There *are* some frequency based effects, because there are some atoms in space, but they are minor.  In the lab, we've created strong vacuums and never observed the effect you suggest.

As with all of science, that doesn't mean it's not true.  Perhaps we just haven't found the right way to observe the effect you see.  Maybe you will be the first to see it, and get to name the effect!  However, from a scientific perspective, without empirical evidence to suggest this is happening, any speculation is just that -- speculation.

Comment: nice thoughtful answer. It is true that there is gas particles and other stuff in space they may effect different wavelength of light differently because all photons do not act the same?

Comment: As far as the sunset it would seem that more blue is pulled out by the atmosphere allowing the red to pass and the opposite in water.

Comment: Yes, there are small amounts of hydrogen present in space.  The effect is minor, but it does exist.  And yes, you are correct.  In the case of the sunset, the effect is caused by scattering of the blue photons by the air.  In the case of the water, the water actually absorbs the red photons.  Those different effects do cause strikingly different outcomes.  It just goes to show how important it is to be aware of the medium the light is traveling through!

Comment: If you are interested in looking further, consider reading up on [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) and [Mie scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mie_scattering).  They're the driving factors for the colors of a sunset

Comment: i am ,,\/  (^_^)